# symfony 2 - twig - How view more (20) fields with use "prototype"?

Tags: symfony

I want view 20 same fields (name: matchday) with use "prototype".
I have a code like this:

Form:

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder
        ->add('matchday', 'collection', array(
            'allow_add' => true,
            'type' => new MatchdayType(),
        ))
   ...
   }
```

and View (Twig):

```
<form action="{{ path('meet_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
 {% for i in 1..20 %}
  {{ form_widget(form.matchday.vars.prototype) }}
{% endfor %}
   <p>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
   </p>
</form>
```

but I don' know how use iteration in this code with "prototype" .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is only a model that you can use to create new fields in the form's collection, but it's not really a field per say. If you want to display 20 empty fields from the beginning, you have basically two choices:

1. add 20 empty 'matchday' objects in the form object in your controller before creating the form
2. use Javascript (jQuery) to add the fields in the view on the client side

The first solution would give something like this:

```
$meet = new Meet();

for ($i=0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $matchday = new MatchDay();
    $meet->getMatchdays->add($matchday);
}

$form = $this->createForm(new MeetType(), $meet);
```

For the second solution, you have a good example in the Symfony Cookbook about form collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html